Translating model fields in Django - are choices a valid alternative?
I am trying to figure out the best way to translate model fields in my Django application.
After looking at the available libraries (django-modeltranslation, django-modeltrans, etc.) I started thinking:
What if I set all the fields that I know will require translation as choices using enums?
That way, translations can be handled just like everything else across the application.
When creating objects in the Django admin, instead of typing the values I will simply choose them from a dropdown and create one object per choice (or more if there are permutations of multiple fields). This won't be a problem because I already know what the objects will be, and if I ever have to create more I can just add choices.
I guess there are some drawbacks:

Whenever I need to add a new object, I first need to add the choice to the code and redeploy instead of just doing it from the Django admin diretcly
Users won't be able to add their own objects (which is fine as I don't plan to give them that option anyway)

I haven't found much online listing this as a valid alternative.
Am I missing anything here?

Field values are written to database, they're not going to be translated by gettext during deserialization.

I am not sure I understand what you are trying to say.
If for example my choice tuple is FRESHMAN = "FR", _("Freshman"), it is true that "FR" will be saved to the database and not translated, but I can use gettext_lazy and have the translation of "Freshman", so I don't see that as a problem. No?
